# First Section Title Clashes With Header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titles

My first section title clashes with my header, but does not for any subsequent section titles. How can I fix this?

[image: First Section Title Clashes]

[image: Subsequenty Section Titles Do Not Clash]

```
%Preamble
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=25mm, right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} %Formats page
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Allows images
\graphicspath{ {images/} } %Sets image folder location
\usepackage[useregional,showdow]{datetime2} %Allows dynamically updating date
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage} %Headers and Footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{
    \title{XXX: Xxxx 12 Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxx - Xxxxxxxxx 1}\\ \author{Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxxx Xxxxx}\\
    XXX: 12345678 $\vert$ XXX: 12345678}
\fancyfoot[C]{$\thepage$ of $\pageref{LastPage}$}

\fancypagestyle{empty}{\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyhead{} \fancyfoot[C]{$\thepage$ of $\pageref{LastPage}$}}



%Document Information
\title{XXX: Xxxx 12 Xxxxxxxxx Xxxxxxxxxxx - Xxxxxxxxx 1}
\author{Xxxx Xxxx Xxxxxx Xxxxx}


%Document Content
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Question 1}
\setcounter{page}{2}


\pagebreak
\section*{Question 2}

\pagebreak
\section*{Question 3}

\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MWE generates the following warning of package `fancyhdr`:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
 Make it at least 34.43335pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

The fix is to increase `\headheight` as needed. This can be done by option `headheight` of package `geometry`:

```
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=25mm,
  right=25mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  headheight=34.5pt,
]{geometry}
```